# Auto Complete with Redis - fetching database

Tags: python, redis, autocomplete, prefix

I'm doing an **autocomplete** project with **REDIS** in Python. I realized I had to use a combination of hash (as datatype) and sorted sets. My question is how I can fetch some sorted data as a prefix with a score of 0? (Initial storage)

t     0
ta    0
tak   0
take  0
tal   0
talk  0

I expect to make it easier for doctors to prescribe my company's drug database with AUTOCOMPLETE

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.